# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161 while trying to click on a link in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

```
<a href="@{{ post.user.profileUrl }}">@ {{ post.user.name }}</a>
```

is the line which is creating the error, it is supposed to link to the profile of the user

simply doing

```
<h2>@{{ post.user.profileUrl }}</h2>
```

is giving the right address, and typing out that address is also taking me to the right page, but with that link it is giving the error

route files

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('auth/login');
});

Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::post('/posts', 'PostController@create');

Route::get('users/{user}', 'UserController@index')->name('user.index');
```

Anyone please help...

Comment: Please show up your routes file!

Comment: You still need to have php syntax within {{ }}. Latter is basically just an echo statement (wrapped in character escape function).

Comment: @SaumyaRastogi route list is updated, please give a look

Comment: @devk the statement inside {{ }} is just giving out the address of the profile link, which is given to href, so it creates a link to the specific address

Answer (score 0):

On your route/web.php:

```
Route::get('/post/user/profile', 'PostUserController@profile')->name('post.user.profile');
```

And then in your view:
     `<a href="{{ route('post.user.profile') }}">Profile</a>`

Ps. I went as simple as possible, because the way I've used the routes here doesn't make much sense for me.

Comment: No, I am pulling it from the json response which is being generated, and post comes as a loop from posts.

Comment: where 1 is the id of the user

Comment: What do you have on class UserController, method index() ?

Comment: How `<a href="@{{ post.user.profileUrl }}">@ {{ post.user.name }}</a>` is being printed in your frontend?

Comment: UserController > index pulls the info of the user from the database and returns to the view which shows the profile with the user's info

Comment: the code shows the name of the user as per post.user.name, and it is made as a link with the address of post.user.profileUrl, but , don't know why, it is showing the error

Comment: Did you removed the @ on your href? Why are you using it?

Comment: No, I didn't remove it

Comment: Why are you using it?

Comment: because I am writing javascript inside blade and no php variable, that is why

Comment: Nice. Didn't know about it!

Comment: But just paste the html that you get on console for you a tag here. Maybe it is parsing something wrong on frontend.

Comment: it is just giving error, no html preview of that sort is generated in the console

Comment: Ok, I think the problem is the address I am putting in, is appending after the current address, so can you tell me how I can make it just go to the specified address.